# Backbone, Underscore, Require.js routing and template issues (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined )

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, require

Need a help for a very weird situation I am in with BB, _, and require. I use Grunt's assemble.io to precompile my html, so at any given moment I have all my templates in one and the same file. I will be more clear, I have this is my index.html:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="main-container">
       <script type="text/template" id="login-template"> 
          bla bla bla
       </script>
       <script type="text/template" id="register-template">
         tralalala
       </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my router:

```
define(['backbone', 'underscore', '../views/homeView', '../views/registerUserView' ],            function(Backbone, _, HomeView, RegisterUserView) {

var homeView = new HomeView(),
    registerUserView = new RegisterUserView();

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      '' : 'home',
      'register/:id': 'registerUser'
    }
 });

var router = new Router();
router.on('route:home', function(){
   homeView.render();
});
router.on('route:registerUser', function(id){
  registerUserView.render(id);
});

Backbone.history.start();

return Router;
});
```

This is my Register View:

```
define(['backbone', 'underscore'], function(Backbone, _) {

  var RegisterUserView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el : '.main-container',

  render : function (id) {
      var _this = this,
          _template = _.template($('#reg-user-main-template').html(), {} );
         //todo: create the switch 
      _this.$el.html(_template);
    },

    initialize: function() {
   }
 });

 return RegisterUserView;
```

});

I have a button with href="#register/1", that when I click gives me the:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined localhost/js/libs/underscore-amd/underscore.js:1180

So I know that this happens, because the _template = _.template($('#reg-user-main-template').html(), {} ); is getting an "undefined" for  $('#reg-user-main-template'), but I don't know why or how, since all my templates are in the same html file. Any help will be greatly appreciated and I am sure that the Karma or whatever will give you many beers if you help :)

Comment: Isn't passing the template to the `define` callback standard practice when using require.js? I don't see `#reg-user-main-template` anywhere,  there is a `#register-template` though. And putting your templates inside `<div>`s that are probably going to get fill with HTML is a bad idea, your templates will disappear as soon as something does `$('.main-container').html(...)`.

Comment: Well I wanted to make names shorter for convenience and than I forgot to rename the second one. Actually you are right, I was putting my templates in the "main-container" and I was deleting them. I feel very stupid for something this easy, sometimes the obvious bugs are harder to find. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Some of the hardest bugs to see are the ones staring you right in the face, the things that couldn't possibly go wrong.